# Angular Material - Sliders and oninput()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-material

I'm working with Angular Material for a web application. Normally, I use the `<input>` tag when using slider bars. In there, I can use the JavaScript function `oninput()` to check if there is any activity. This sends a number to a server-side script. In my code, this sends a value for brightness (controlling a web-enabled light system).

```
<input type="range" id="c1" max="255" oninput="hexToRGB(document.getElementById('color').value);">
```

With Angular Material, `<input>` isn't used, instead opting to utilize `<md-button>`. If I try `oninput()` with this new syntax, I get no response.

```
<md-slider flex min="0" max="255" ng-model="color.red" aria-label="red" id="red-slider" oninput="hexToRGB(document.getElementById('color').value);" class='md-primary'></md-slider>
```

What is the best way to approach this problem? Should I stick to using `<input>` sliders? Is there an alternative to using `oninput()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) instead of `oninput`

```
<md-slider flex min="0" max="255" ng-model="color.red" ng-change="modelChanched()" aria-label="red" id="red-slider" class='md-primary'></md-slider>
```

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJerLq)